# Regular expression for match 8 numbers starting with 40|41|43

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression to match exactly this kind of format:

40XXXXXX
41XXXXXX
43XXXXXX

So far i have this `\d{2}(^40?|^41?|^43?)\d{6}`

But it doesn't work, i've spend hours in http://regexr.com/ trying to make it work without luck

Appreciate your help

Comment: I don't understand why you used `\d{2}` at the beginning of your regex. Also, you need to match `$` the end of string. `^4[013]\d{6}$`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following regex

```
/^4(0|1|3)[0-9]{6}$/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yP3gZ6/1)

Or,

```
/^4[013][0-9]{6}$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yP3gZ6/2)

**Explanation:**

1. `^4`: Start with `4`
2. `(0|1|3)`: Matches 0 or 1 or 3. `|` is OR in regex
3. `[013]`: Matches any one digit from the character class
4. `[0-9]{6}`: Matches any number from 0 to 9 exactly six times

Comment: Thanks! You my friend are a life saviour!

Comment: You still can use `[013]` instead of `(0|1|3)`.